# TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, typeerror, python-2.x

I'm trying to write a short program which allows the user to input a list of numbers into an input() function, and then using the add_25 function add 25 to each item in a list.

I get the following error when the program runs: `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

I tried dividing the numbers using a comma. This is the program:

```
testlist = [2,6,2]

def add_25(mylist):

    for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
        mylist[i] = mylist[i] + 25

    return mylist

print add_25(testlist)

actual_list = input("Please input a series of numbers, divided by a comma:")

print add_25(actual_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2 `input()` will eval the string and in this case it will create a tuple, and as tuples are immutable you'll get that error.

```
>>> eval('1, 2, 3')
(1, 2, 3)
```

[It is safer to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) `raw_input` with a `list-comprehension` here:

```
inp = raw_input("Please input a series of numbers, divided by a comma:")
actual_list = [int(x) for x in inp.split(',')]
```

Or if you're not worried about user's input then simply convert the tuple to list by passing it to `list()`.

---

Also note that as you're trying to update the list in-place inside of the function it makes no sense to return the list unless you want to assign another variable to the same list object. Either return a new list or don't return anything.

Comment: Thank you! On a side note, what is "eval"?

Comment: @Artyom721 eval is built-in function in Python.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval

Answer (score 0):

The function `input` reads a string *and evaluates it as a Python expression*.  Thus, the comma-separated list becomes a tuple of values, these are passed to `add_25()`, and this function tries to assign to `mylist[i]` something.

And tuples are immutable, they do not support item assignment (on purpose).

You could use `actual_list = list(input(...))` to convert the tuple to a `list` (which supports item assignment).

But every time someone uses `input()`, one has to warn him:  `input()` is a security risk.  It *evaluates* the input of the *user* and thus might *execute* arbitrary things the *user* typed.  This means that your program will perform what the user asks it to, with your permissions.  This is normally not what is considered a good design.

If you always will be the only user or if you trust all users of your program completely, then so be it.

Comment: Note that as `ast.literal_eval` is the safe version of `eval`, one should really use: `ast.literal_eval(raw_input(...))` and nearly never `input(...)`.

Comment: Yes, but in this case the programmer intended to parse a list or comma-separated values, so not a literal.  But thanks for the pointer to that function; didn't know that one yet.

Comment: As `ast.literal_eval("1, 2, 3")` results in `(1, 2, 3)` just as `eval` does, it actually is a drop in replacement in this case.

Comment: OH, I see.  A tuple counts as a literal in this meaning.  That's really a good thing, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all the `input()` aspects covered in the other answers, I'd like to add this completely different aspect:

Your function `add_25()` is probably not supposed to *change* its input.  Yours does, or tries to, and fails because tuples do not allow that.

But you actually do not have to change the input (and you should not, because this is not good style due to its ugly side-effects).  Instead you could just return a new tuple:

```
def add_25(mytuple):
    return tuple(x + 25 for x in mytuple)
```

This way, nothing is assigned to a tuple, just a new tuple is created and returned.

Answer (score -1):

```
def test_tuples_of_one_look_peculiar(self):
    self.assertEqual( __,(1).__class__)
    self.assertEqual(__, (1,).__class__)
```

Comment: Kindly specify your problem in proper way.

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)